# Set width and height of an image loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I load an image on my web page using `jQuery` like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#mySelect').change(function () {
        var selectedCity = $('#mySelect').val();
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(eval(selectedCity).lan, eval(selectedCity).lng);
        venueMap.setCenter(myLatLng);
        image = 'img.png';
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: venueMap,
            icon: image
        });
        marker.setMap(venueMap);
    });
});
```

how can I set the width and the height of the image?

I've tried 
`image.width = 100;` and `image.height = 50;` (as js statements) with no success.

As asked my relevant HTML code:

```
....
<body>
        <center>
            <h2>Testing jQuery with Google Maps</h2>
            <br>
            <br>
            <select id="mySelect">
                <option value="Rome">Rome</option>
                <option value="London">London</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>

            <div id="map"></div>
        </center>
    </body>
.....
```

Comment: please post your relevant html code - you have to set the size of the html element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add other properties of the image as shown on Google Maps [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex)

```
    var image = {
      url: 'image.png',
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
      size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
      // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      // The anchor for this image is the base at (0, 32).
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
    };
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can select any element using select query like `$('#image-id')` .`.css()` function is used to set css style in a particular element . Pass the value inside of the `css()` function.

`$('#map').css({'height':'50px;','width':'50px;'});` . `map` is the ID of that particular  `image` element .

```
$(function () {
    $('#mySelect').change(function () {
        var selectedCity = $('#mySelect').val();
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(eval(selectedCity).lan, eval(selectedCity).lng);
        venueMap.setCenter(myLatLng);
        image = 'img.png';
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: venueMap,
            icon: image
        });
        marker.setMap(venueMap);
    });


$('#map').css({'height':'50px;','width':'50px;'});
});
```

Comment: The image I'd like to change the size of hasn't any ID.

Comment: Updated, try this now.

Comment: The Map is inside the `<div id="map"></div>` element, right ?

Comment: Yes it is, @Mohammad Faisal 's solution is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery, you can use the prop functions:

```
$(element).prop('width', 100);
$(element).prop('height', 50);
```

where $(element) is the selector for the image tag. The first argument to prop() is the name of the property/attribute and the second argument is the new value for the property.

For pure JavaScript, you need to select the element and then change the property as:

```
document.getElementById('img').width = 100;
document.getElementById('img').height= 50;
```

Where 'img' is the Id of the image. You can also use alternative selectors like getElementsByClassName or getElementsByName.